# Count dividing by 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all, I have researched everywhere to get this query sorted and I cant find an answer that solved my issue so here it is.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    [Report Date],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] = '0' OR [standing_load] = '0'THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS [Zero Values],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > '12' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Green Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < '12' AND [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] >= '10'
          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Yellow Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < '10' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Red Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] IS NULL OR [standing_load]  IS NULL THEN 1 END)AS [Null Values],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Total]


FROM [dbo].[dc_chargers$]
WHERE [Report Date] = 'March 2016' AND sla_no NOT LIKE ('%South%')
GROUP BY [Report Date]
```

Bear in mind that I copy and paste this query to get results for several months of the year. The result that I am expecting is the count of how many fields fall under the 'green', 'yellow', 'red' and 'null' value fields as my bosses require this info every month but whenever the [standing_load] value or the [total_ahr_cap] values are 0 - I get a divide by zero error.

I need to have the count of the figures that re divided by 0 as I cannot change them to `NULL` values so how can I get around this as everytime that I get the divide by zero error the query does not count the month of the figures that have the 0 in and I have to change them to `NULL` value but that is giving me inaccurate data.

please see below what the query should look like:

```
Report Date     Green Zone    Yellow Zone   Red Zone    Null Values Total
2015-12-01          276           5            5            16        286
2016-01-01          365           5            5            24        375
2016-02-01          376           4            5            25        384
```

as you can see, it counts all the other months but not the month that has 0 values.

help please!

Comment: you need sums not counts

Comment: @ZahiroMor so do i just change the count for sum?

Comment: basically - yes. check my answer - i changed a few more things like removing quotes from number values and adding a [standing_load] is not null. try it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid `Divide by 0` exception in you query, in each case where you do divide operation first check if divider is greater than 0. Also why comparing numerical values to string?

Also your 5th `case` is missing `else` part.

See code below:

```
SELECT
    [Report Date],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] = 0 OR [standing_load] = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS [Zero Values],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [standing_load] > 0 and [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Green Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [standing_load] > 0 and [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < 12 AND [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] >= 10
          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Yellow Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [standing_load] > 0 and [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Red Zone],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [standing_load] > 0 and [total_ahr_cap] IS NULL OR [standing_load]  IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)AS [Null Values],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [standing_load] > 0 and [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Total]


FROM [dbo].[dc_chargers$]
WHERE [Report Date] = 'March 2016' AND sla_no NOT LIKE ('%South%')
GROUP BY [Report Date]
```

Also a small advice because I'm not sure if it is acceptable in your solution but I'd change count to `sum` and nulls to 0.

Comment: On this one i dont get the error anymore which is great but the count of 0 values is 404 but the total amount of cells is 384 and i should only have like 10-20 cells that have the value of 0 in either the divisor or dividend?

Comment: Shouldn't that CASE end with 'THEN 1 ELSE NULL END' ?

Comment: @RichBenner which CASE are you talking about?

Comment: The Zero Values one that you mentioned. It's looking for whether total_ahr_cap or standing_load are zeroes, it's then returning a NULL if they are and a 1 if they both have a value. You'll end up with a column called 'Zero Values' with a 1 if there aren't any zero values in either column.

Comment: @RichBenner i just swiched the values around so if there is a 0 to count it as 1 otherwise NULL and that seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    [Report Date],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] = 0 OR [standing_load] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Zero Values],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > 12 and [standing_load] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Green Zone],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < 12 AND [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] >= 10 and [standing_load] is not null
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Yellow Zone],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] < 10 and [standing_load] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Red Zone],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] IS NULL OR [standing_load]  IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Null Values],
    sum(CASE WHEN [total_ahr_cap] / [standing_load] > 0 and [standing_load] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total]

FROM [dbo].[dc_chargers$]
WHERE [Report Date] = 'March 2016' AND sla_no NOT LIKE ('%South%')
GROUP BY [Report Date]
```

Comment: it still gives me the divide by 0 error on this one mate